# temp files in memory in java program

Tags: java, performance, memory, large-files, temporary-files

Is there a way to force the temporary files created in a java program in memory? Since I use several large xml file, I would have advantages in this way? Should I use a transparent method that allows me to not upset the existing application.

UPDATE: I'm looking at the source code and I noticed that it uses libraries (I can not change) which requires the path of those files ...

Thanks

Comment: "More NIO Features" in JDK7 allows you to provide your own file system implementation (wont work with legacy file APIs though).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to create a RAM disk and then point the system property java.io.tmpdir to that RAM disk.

Comment: Do you know how to do it on linux?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir

Comment: For my case it is the only solution (actually a trick) feasible, even if it is not closely related to java. Thanks

Comment: @Lyther: On my computer my entire `/tmp` is tmpfs, i.e., stored in RAM (and swapped out if necessary). In case you're short on RAM, you could use also [compressed swap](http://code.google.com/p/compcache).

Answer (score 2):

XML is just a `String`, why not just reference `Strings` in memory, I think the File interface is a distraction. Use `StringBuilder` if you need to manipulate the data. Use `StringBuffer` if you need thread safety. Put them in a type safe `Map` if you have a variable number of things that need to be looked up on with a key.

If you absolutely have to keep the `File` interface, then create a `InMemoryFileWriter` that wraps `ByteArrayOutputStream` and `ByteArrayInputStream` to keep them in memory, but again I think the whole `File` in memory thing is a bad decision if you just want to cache things in memory, that is a lot of overhead when a simple `String` would do.

Comment: Or `byte[]` or similar (`ByteBuffer`). XML can specify which character encoding it is in, which means it really needs to be stored in bytes.

Comment: not really, Java Strings are Unicode so not problems with encoding, especially since the apparently application is generating the XML ( hence the temp file solution), not reading it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use files if you don't have to. Consider `com.google.common.io.FileBackedOutputStream` from Guava:

> An OutputStream that starts buffering to a byte array, but switches to file buffering once the data reaches a configurable size.

Answer (score 0):

You probably can *force* the default behaviour of `java.io.File` with some reflection magic, but I'm sure you don't want to do that as it can lead to unpredicted behaviour. You're better off providing a mechanism where it would be possible to switch between usual and in-memory behaviour, and route all calls via this mechanism.

Look at [this example](http://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips/java.nio/how-to-create-a-memory-mapped-file-3.html), it shows how to use file API to create in-memory files.

Comment: By reflection magic I mean tricks like in this presentation: http://www.javaspecialists.eu/talks/oslo09/ReflectionMadness.pdf - in my opinion this is highly dangerous and should be avoided at all costs.

Comment: memory mapped file io is __not__ the same as in memory storage, it just makes the file on the device look like memory, big difference.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have control over the the streams that are being used to write to the file -

Do you absolutely want the in-memory behavior? If all that you want to do is reduce the number of system calls to write to the disk, you can wrap the FileOutputStream in a [BufferedOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) (with appropriately big buffer size) and write to this [BufferedOutputStream](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedOutputStream.html) (or [BufferedWriter](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/BufferedWriter.html)) instead of writing directly to the original FileOutputStream.
(This does require a change in the existing application)