# not able to change java.io.tmpdir

Tags: java, linux, properties, command

I am trying to change the java.io.tmpdir directory using this command

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/temporary
```

But this doesnot succeed and displays the 'Usage' of the java command.
I am doing this in a RHEL machine.

Thanks in advance

I have deployed an application on WebLogiv which uses axis2 version 1.5. I find that axis2 1.5 using java.io.tmpdir to store its temp files. I want the location where these temp files are stored. Where in the weblogic do I specify the java.io.tmpdir value

Answer (score 18):

You need to use that command as part of running a program, not just `java -Dkey=value`.

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/temporary com.foo.Bar
```

where `com.foo.Bar` is the class which contains the `main` method.

Alternatively, you can do this programmatically.

```
System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/temporary");
```

Comment: This `System.setProperty("java.io.tmpdir", "/temporary");` is the best way i think.

Comment: Setting the java.io.tmpdir from the command line doesn't work, it gets reset to the default of /tmp

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1924159/594793

Specifically, this part:

> A different value may be given to this system property when the Java virtual machine is invoked, but programmatic changes to this property are not guaranteed to have any effect upon the the temporary directory used by this method.