# modify temp value to do mutiple build in ant

Tags: ant, build

I want to do multiple builds in ant but the files in /tmp getting cleared by one build and fails the other. How to set a different value for TEMP variable. Tried setting env key="TEMPDIR" path="/tmp/mytemp1", env key="TEMP" path="/tmp/mytemp1", env key="TMP" path="/tmp/mytemp1", env key=" java.io.tmpdir" path="/tmp/mytemp1" but no luck. In short, how can I change value of TEMP for each process?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you look at using the standard ANT [tempfile](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tempfile.html) task to create temporary files.

A more common approach to this problem is to create a "build" directory in the project workspace and a "clean" target to remove files that are created by the ANT build:

```
<property name="build.dir" location"build"/>
<property name="classes.dir" location"${build.dir}/classes"/>

<target name="compile">
  <mkdir dir="${classes.dir}"/>
  <javac srcdir="${src.dir}" destdir="${classes.dir}"...
</target>

<target name="clean">
  <delete dir="${build.dir}"/>
</target>
```

To ensure a clean build of the project you run it as follows:

```
ant clean compile
```

## Update

Other stackoverflow questions related to setting temp directory

- [not able to change java.io.tmpdir](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10108262/not-able-to-change-java-io-tmpdir)
- [Environment variable to control java.io.tmpdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I am looking for not to clean up the files. I want to have different tmp dirs for each build so that one build will not affect another. How can I assign value to java.io.tmpdir in ant at runtime?

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have seen these posts earlier but I didn't get proper way to implement this is ant script. I tried using env, key pair in exec task but it ddn't work. I am trying trying to provide different tmp value in exec task which will invoke runassembler command and this runassember using the /tmp to pack the ears.

Comment: @Baiju Sounds like you're paddling upstream. Using a "clean" target is the standard way to solve this problem. Personally I like to see the files created by my build, rather than have them hidden away in the /tmp directory.