# what is java.io.tmp significance

Tags: java, tomcat

Can you please tell what is significance of "java.io.tmp" directory?

I noticed this directory is created under webapps folder in my tomcat.

Thanks!

Comment: If you have a directory called "java.io.tmp" under your webapps folder when you run Tomcat, then something is very wrong: you have some code that is stupidly creating that directory instead of using the `java.io.tmp` *system property* that points to a temporary directory.

Answer (score 0):

It is not directory, it is property points to a directory to be used as temp folder(directory happens to have same name as property is a tomcat decision).   When you want to create temporary file, this property is used as the location for the file. Some [example](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.io/CreateTempFile.html)

```
 File tempFile = File.createTempFile("pattern", ".suffix");
 tempFile.deleteOnExit();
```

JVM by default copies the value from TMP/TEMP environment variable. The value can be set when JVM starts. Tomcat sets this for rest of the application to use.

Related : [Environment variable to control java.io.tmpdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir)

Answer (score 0):

The name itself is a great clue. Its java.IO.TMP, which common sense would tell us is about temporary ios. Since the java.io package is about files then it probably adds up this is a path to store temporary files.