# Solr indexer...SolrException:Bad Request

Tags: solr, nutch, solrj, websolr

When I start solrindex, I have the exception
    `org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request`
this is the hadoop.log file content

```
...
2013-02-11 17:01:22,079 INFO  anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter - Anchor deduplication is: off
2013-02-11 17:01:22,079 INFO  indexer.IndexingFilters - Adding org.apache.nutch.indexer.anchor.AnchorIndexingFilter
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: content dest: content
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: title dest: title
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: host dest: host
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: segment dest: segment
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: boost dest: boost
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: digest dest: digest
2013-02-11 17:01:22,222 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: tstamp dest: tstamp
2013-02-11 17:01:22,223 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: id
2013-02-11 17:01:22,223 INFO  solr.SolrMappingReader - source: url dest: url
2013-02-11 17:01:23,940 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Indexing 250 documents
2013-02-11 17:01:23,952 INFO  solr.SolrWriter - Deleting 0 documents
2013-02-11 17:01:24,780 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0001
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad Request

Bad Request

 request: http://localhost:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:427)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:249)
at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.write(SolrWriter.java:124)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:55)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.write(IndexerOutputFormat.java:44)
at     org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.write(ReduceTask.java:457)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$3.collect(ReduceTask.java:497)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:304)
at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerMapReduce.reduce(IndexerMapReduce.java:53)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:519)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
2013-02-11 17:01:25,330 ERROR solr.SolrIndexer - java.io.IOException: Job failed!
```

I think that i have some problem with my schema.xml
this is it

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!--
    Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or
    more contributor license agreements. See the NOTICE file
    distributed with this work for additional information regarding
    copyright ownership. The ASF licenses this file to You under the
    Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License"); you may not use
    this file except in compliance with the License. You may obtain
    a copy of the License at
    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0 Unless required by
    applicable law or agreed to in writing, software distributed
    under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT
    WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
    See the License for the specific language governing permissions
    and limitations under the License.
-->
<!--
    Description: This document contains Solr 3.1 schema definition to
    be used with Solr integration currently build into Nutch. See
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-442
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-699
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-994
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-997
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1058
    https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-1232
    and
    http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/branches/branch_3x/solr/
    example/solr/conf/schema.xml?view=markup
    for more info.
-->
<schema name="nutch" version="1.5">
<types>
    <fieldType name="string" class="solr.StrField" sortMissingLast="true"
        omitNorms="true"/> 
    <fieldType name="long" class="solr.TrieLongField" precisionStep="0"
        omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="float" class="solr.TrieFloatField" precisionStep="0"
        omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>
    <fieldType name="date" class="solr.TrieDateField" precisionStep="0"
        omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="0"/>

    <fieldType name="text" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory"
                ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"
                catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="1" catenateAll="0"
                splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.EnglishPorterFilterFactory"
                protected="protwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    <fieldType name="url" class="solr.TextField"
        positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory"
                generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
</types>
<fields>
    <field name="id" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
<!--    <field name="site" type="string" stored="false" indexed="true"/>  -->
    <!-- core fields -->
    <field name="segment" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="digest" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="boost" type="float" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

    <!-- fields for index-basic plugin -->
    <field name="host" type="string" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="url" type="url" stored="true" indexed="true"
        required="true"/>
    <field name="content" type="text" stored="false" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="title" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="cache" type="string" stored="true" indexed="false"/>
    <field name="tstamp" type="date" stored="true" indexed="false"/>

    <!-- fields for index-anchor plugin -->
    <field name="anchor" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for index-more plugin -->
    <field name="type" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="contentLength" type="long" stored="true"
        indexed="false"/>
    <field name="lastModified" type="date" stored="true"
        indexed="false"/>
    <field name="date" type="date" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for languageidentifier plugin -->
    <field name="lang" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for subcollection plugin -->
    <field name="subcollection" type="string" stored="true"
        indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>

    <!-- fields for feed plugin (tag is also used by microformats-reltag)-->
    <field name="author" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="tag" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/>
    <field name="feed" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
    <field name="publishedDate" type="date" stored="true"
        indexed="true"/>
    <field name="updatedDate" type="date" stored="true"
        indexed="true"/>

    <!-- fields for creativecommons plugin -->
    <field name="cc" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true"
        multiValued="true"/>

<!--    <field name="Metatags" type="string" stored="true" indexed="true" multiValued="true"/> -->

</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
<defaultSearchField>content</defaultSearchField>
<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="OR"/>
```

I coped schema.xml from nutch/conf folder to the solr/conf, and now I'm  use nutch 1.6 solr 3.6.2 and apache tomcat 6.0.36...i think i will help to understand th e problem.
I have not any errors in apahce log file...
olso i change solr-solrj-3.4.jar file in nutch/lib folder with solr-solrj-3.6.2.jar from solr/dist/ folder...

i can show my solrindex-mapping.xml

```
<mapping>
<!-- Simple mapping of fields created by Nutch IndexingFilters
     to fields defined (and expected) in Solr schema.xml.

         Any fields in NutchDocument that match a name defined
         in field/@source will be renamed to the corresponding
         field/@dest.
         Additionally, if a field name (before mapping) matches
         a copyField/@source then its values will be copied to 
         the corresponding copyField/@dest.

         uniqueKey has the same meaning as in Solr schema.xml
         and defaults to "id" if not defined.
     -->
<fields>
    <field dest="content" source="content"/>
    <field dest="title" source="title"/>
    <field dest="host" source="host"/>
    <field dest="segment" source="segment"/>
    <field dest="boost" source="boost"/>
    <field dest="digest" source="digest"/>
    <field dest="tstamp" source="tstamp"/>
    <field dest="id" source="url"/>
    <copyField source="url" dest="url"/>
</fields>
<uniqueKey>id</uniqueKey>
</mapping>
```

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: can you check the solr logs it would have the details for the error

Comment: solr logs should have the request. Is the solr server started ? with the default core ??

Comment: Thanks for comment, it was helpful.
 I tried to run solr with apache tomcat....but now, whene i tried to run solr server, it started to index.....but now I have the new error in nutch whene i start to crawl.. i have this exception

( ERROR mapred.FileOutputCommitter - Mkdirs failed to create file:/home/hayk/apps/1/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/crawl/crawldb/1450820463/_temporary
2013-02-12 15:06:07,269 WARN  mapred.LocalJobRunner - job_local_0002
java.io.IOException: The temporary job-output directory file:/home/hayk/apps/1/apache-nutch-1.6/bin/crawl/crawldb/1450820463/_temporary doesn't exist!)

Answer (score 0):

Use the Nutch config(nutch-default.xml) to set the path to the temporary directory:

```
<property>
 <name>mapred.temp.dir</name>
 <value>/tmp</value>
 <description>A shared directory for temporary files.</description>
</property>
```

**References**

- [Nutch Configuration Files](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchConfigurationFiles)
- [MapReduce Default Configuration](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.0.4/mapred-default.html)
- [Configure Tomcat's File and Webapp Paths](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/GettingNutchRunningWithDebian#Configure_Tomcat.27s_File_and_Webapp_Paths)
- [Specify temp/working directory for crawl](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NUTCH-159)
- [Environment variable to control java.io.tmpdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/1113772)