# The system cannot find the path while createTempFile

Tags: java

I get an exception saying 'the system cannot find the path specified' while calling java function `createTempFile("test", "test")`.
Tried googling but no luck. 
Does anyone know from where java gets its default temp path and how can it be not found?
Windows variables seem to be correct and changing them does not affect java.

Comment: check whats in String dirName = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"); And also maybe try define tempDir direclty with: File.createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)

Comment: File.CreateTempFile("test", "test") is prettymuch the while code :)

Comment: If uncertain, you can also attach the runtime sources (src.zip) to your IDE, start debugging and step into the `createTempFile()` method to see where it fails

Answer (score 17, accepted):

> **Does anyone know from where java gets its default temp path**

It is read from the `java.io.tmpdir` property.

```
Files.createTempFile("test", "test");
```

essentially calls `java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.createTempFile(null, prefix, suffix, attrs);` which again calls `java.nio.file.TempFileHelper.create(dir, prefix, suffix, false, attrs);`. There, if `dir` is null, it is set to `tmpdir` which is declared as follows:

```
private static final Path tmpdir =
    Paths.get(doPrivileged(new GetPropertyAction("java.io.tmpdir")));
```

You can set the property explicitly as shown in the answer from @Joni. If you do not set it explicitly, the JVM initializes it to a platform specific default value at startup - see also [Environment variable to control java.io.tmpdir?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1924136/environment-variable-to-control-java-io-tmpdir)

> **and how can it be not found?**

If the property `java.io.tmpdir` points to an invalid directory, the temporary file can not be created.

Answer (score 7):

Independently of how the default value is obtained, you can set the temporary files directory by setting the system property `java.io.tmpdir` when starting the JVM:

```
java -Djava.io.tmpdir=/path/to/where/ever/you/like YourClass
```

If you want to know where the default value comes from, you'll have to read the source code for your JVM. For example, OpenJDK on Windows calls the API function [`GetTempPathW`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364992%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (search for the file `java_props_md.c` in the JDK source code), which looks up the path in environment variables and registry in the following way:

> The `GetTempPath` function checks for the existence of environment variables in the following order and uses the first path found:
>
> 1. The path specified by the TMP environment variable.
> 2. The path specified by the TEMP environment variable.
> 3. The path specified by the USERPROFILE environment variable.
> 4. The Windows directory.
>
> Note that the function does not verify that the path exists, nor does it test to see if the current process has any kind of access rights to the path.

Comment: But if i change the TMP env variables then java.io.tmpdir still prints to pervious oodatuim?

Comment: Assuming "oodatuim" means directory: maybe your program is launched with a script that resets TMP, maybe you need to restart the system for the change to take effect, maybe your JVM doesn't use the GetTempPath function, it's impossible to know with the data provided.

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
String path = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
```

See: **[get property method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getProperties%28%29)**

And to add it here for completeness sake, there's also the methods **[createTempFile(String prefix,String suffix)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29)** and **[createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29)** methods from Java's **[file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html)** class.

**Here is my code to fin path of temp file and find temp path:**

```
public class GetTempFilePathExample
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {   

        try{

            //create a temp file
            File temp = File.createTempFile("temp-file-name", ".tmp"); 

            System.out.println("Temp file : " + temp.getAbsolutePath());

        //Get tempropary file path
            String absolutePath = temp.getAbsolutePath();
            String tempFilePath = absolutePath.
                substring(0,absolutePath.lastIndexOf(File.separator));

            System.out.println("Temp file path : " + tempFilePath);

        }catch(IOException e){

            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }
}
```

**Output of this code is :**

```
Temp file : /tmp/temp-file-name3697762749201044262.tmp
Temp file path : /tmp
```