# Setting java.io.tmpdir in Wildfly 8.2

Tags: wildfly-8

I am attempting to set the location of the system property java.io.tmpdir to something other than the default "/tmp" in my standalone.xml file.

I have added the following element after the `<extensions>` element:

`<system-properties>
    <property name="java.io.tmpdir" value="/tmp/wildfly"/>
</system-properties>`

However, when I start up wildfly, I see this in the log file:

```
java.io.tmpdir = /tmp
```

I don't see anywhere in any of the bin*.conf files or the bin*.sh files that's setting this... what am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: You may be out of luck: see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1924576/1789384)

Comment: Thanks... Yeah... I guess that kind of makes sense... I just set it in my standalone.conf file...